# java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkerManager is disposed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

When I made a recycle view on top of a fragment and loaded a data adopter into it the following error occurred crashing the application. Does any one know what this error means?

```
E/WorkController: Loading failed for worker [context]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkerManager is disposed
```

Comment: Post your source code also